# How to handle errors in BlockingObservable without subscribe()?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

for various reasons I have to block on observable like this

```
Foo foo = fooBarNetworkRequestObservable()
   .toBlocking()
   .single();

return foo;
```

But how do I handle errors now? Is is possible without subscribe(new Subscriber .. onError()?. I tried wrapping the code in try-catch but compiler complains that IOException is never thrown in coresponding try-catch block. Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in blocking world so you need try-catch. Since the API can't throw checked exceptions, we wrap them into `RuntimeException` for you:

```
try {
    source.toBlocking.single();
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    if (ex.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
        // handle IOException
    } else {
        throw ex; // something other happened
    }
}
```